# Conditioning on a conditioned variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $A,B,C$ and $D$ be random variables. Does it make sense to talk about a probability of the form $$p((A|B) \mid C)$$ or $$p((A|B)\mid (C|D)).$$ And is it possible to reduce these to easier formulas

Comment: "Does it make sense..." No. This has been explained several times on the site, the point is that there is no such object as $(A\mid B)$, random variable or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.   It is nonsense.

The "$\mid$" symbol is *not* a set connective, like "$\cap$", "$\cup$", "$\setminus$", "$\triangle$", or the list concatenator "$,$".

The "$\mid$" symbol is part of the conditional probability measure itself, separating events from conditions.    $\mathsf P(~\textit{events}~\mid~\textit{conditions}~)$

There can only be one.

---

$\mathsf P((A\mid B) \mid C)$ is nonsense, but if you mean the probability that event A happens given B and given C, then that would be $\mathsf P(A\mid B,C)= \mathsf P(A\mid B\cap C)$

$\mathsf P((A\mid B) \mid (C\mid D))$ is even less sensible.   What.   Just, what do you think it means?

Comment: Consider the joint conditional distribution of some $ x_{t} $ and $ \epsilon_{t} = y_{t} + c$, where , $ c $ is a constant. Then, from a textbook about the Kalman filter they state that $$ (
x_{t},\epsilon_{t}) \mid (y_{t-1}, y_{t-2},\ldots, y_{1}) $$ is normally distributed. And from this, they use a classic result about multivariate distributions to deduce a closed form of $ E(x_{t}\mid y_{t}, y_{t-1},\ldots, y_{1}) $. I find this very strange based on your answers. Can you maybe elaborate?

Comment: @New_to_this The uses of the "$\mid$" symbol in those random variable contexts *are inspired* by its use in probability measure of events.  Thus same principle applies: there is always only one conditioning symbol in the structure.

Comment: Okay. So $x_t | (y_{t-1},\ldots, y_1 )$ is a marginal distribution for example ?